# Android Emulator Network is misconfigured. Different settings than officially documented. Why and how to change?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking

The virtual device has the IP address 192.168.232.20. What is the correct IP address to access the host (aka development machine)?

According to [official network documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) the emulated device should have the IP address 10.0.2.15 and the development machine should be accessible via IP 10.0.2.2 with the latter being an alias to the loopback interface of the host.

But for some reason the emulator uses the subnet 192.168.232.*. I guessed and tried 192.168.232.2 to connect to the host, but failed. Somehow my emulator uses a different virtual network configuration than officially documented, but I did not find any config file that looks suspicious.

Two questions:

1. Does anybody experience similar issues and could tell me what the correct host IP is in this case?
2. Where is this (unusual) configuration being set?

Comment: Have you had any luck? I am facing the exact same issue

Comment: I created a new emulated device and the problem was solved

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali Luck for you. Creating new emulated devices does not help me. They get the same, unusual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now with Emulator v29.2.1-5889189 and Android Q so this might was fixed in an update, but the host IP is still `10.0.2.2`.